# Solve the following non linear system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the non-linear system,

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x_{1}' \\
x_{2}' \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-x_{1} \\
x_{2}+x_{1}^2 \end{array} \right) $$

Find the solution of the initial value problem..I couldn't integrate the the equation to find $x_{2}$,since it involves two dependent variables $x_{1}$ and ${x_{2}}$.

Can someone help me for the same..

Thanking in advance

Comment: You want the solution to an initial value problem, but I see no initial values...?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:

$x_1$ is not coupled to $x_2$. From the equation for $x_1'$, it's not hard to find that
\begin{equation}
x_1(t) = e^{-t}x_1(0).
\end{equation}

Can you substitute this into the equation for $x_2'$ and solve from there?

Comment: I tried in that way..I am not getting the answer..